# IE Alpha Png fix isn't working

Tags: css, png, alpha

I have been at this for hours now and getting absolutely no where!

Basically, the PNG's alpha channel isn't fixing it self with TwinHelix plugin. I put an alert in the .HTC file, it fired correctly, the blank image is relative to the HTC file.

```
img, div, input, a, button, p, h1, h2, h3 ,h4 ,h5 {behavior: url('/../_design/iepngfix.htc');}
```

This is the css I'm using in my main.css file, the iepngfix.htc and blank.gif files are in the "_design" folder. All links are correct but the alpha channel is still unaffected :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://pmf.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/ - The login form for example, the yellow and brown buttons aren't being repaired.

Regards, 
Shannon

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You must use url without single Quote and you must use absolute addressing for example

```
behavior: url(/YourRootAddress/YourFileAndFolder/_design/iepngfix.htc);
```

Comment: but I had an alert in the HTC file which fired? so it's obviously seeing the file correctly?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite following what you mean by that? What's wrong with the way I have it if the alert is actually being fired on IE 8? does that not mean that the file is being read correctly?